# HTML Canvas: Scaling image to fit without stretching?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im using the code below to draw and scale an image inside a canvas. The issue being that the image rendered inside is stretched to fit.

If possible, I would like it to be scaled based on width but to maintain its aspect ratio.

Any ideas?

```
//IMAGE LOADER
var canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('image-canvas2');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

// Trigger the imageLoader function when a file has been selected
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', imageLoader, false);

function imageLoader() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx2.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: Do you know that the correct ratio is? You can just apply the right ratio when drawing. If you don't know it, you can render it on the DOM and query the image for its width/height

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can figure out dimensions of the image by adding it to the DOM. Once you know the ratio, you can scale your image to fit within your canvas.

```
ratio = width / height;
width = height * ratio;
height = width / ratio;
```

The following should work whether an image is landscape or portrait.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('image-canvas2');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', imageLoader, false);

function imageLoader() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var ct = document.getElementById('measure'); 
            ct.appendChild(img);
            var wrh = img.width / img.height;
            var newWidth = canvas.width;
            var newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
            if (newHeight > canvas.height) {
                newHeight = canvas.height;
                newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
            }
            ct.removeChild(img);
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, newWidth , newHeight);
        }
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
}
```

```css
/* Add image to the DOM here so user can't see it */
#measure { position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: -100000px;}
canvas { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="image-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<div id="measure"></div>
```

You can [play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/4y52rmz5/2/)

Comment: Great solution! Saved me a lot of work, thanks mate!

Comment: When I try in the responsive view of fireworks, works fine, but when I try from my mobile, it doesn't. Any idea?

Comment: @galeonweb You should ask a new question linked to this one, posting the code you used tried, what the error was and what you expected. Please don't ask new questions under an existing question, it adds too much noise

Comment: Ok, sorry. I wasn't sure if i could ask repeated questions, and how to

Comment: It's not a duplicate if you show your specific usage of the code, your problem is likely something else, which is why a separate question might be helpful for other people that may have the same problems as you