# scaling images to fit on canvas without streching

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, responsive, drawimage

according to the post [HTML Canvas: Scaling image to fit without stretching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047792/html-canvas-scaling-image-to-fit-without-stretching/28048865?noredirect=1#comment82110002_28048865), when I open an image to fit on canvas it Works if I am using the descktop view, but when I i am using a responsive view It doesn't work well.
My application is published in https://www.galeonweb.es/web, and the code I am using to open an image is:

```
var img=new Image();

img.onload=function(){
    var wrh=img.width/img.height;
    var newWidth=canvas.width;
    var newHeight=newWidth/wrh;
    if (newHeight>canvas.height){
        newHeight=canvas.height;
        newWidth=newHeight*wrh;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    //ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, img.width, img.height, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //Coloco la imagen en el canvas

    imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //Extraigo su array       forma.guardarEnHistorico(imgData);
};

img.src=url;
//Cerramos el cuadro de dialogo abrir
ocultarVentana($('#abrir'));
```

On the other hand, I use a responsive CSS with the following code:

```
canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:420px;
    background:white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

and the HTML code is:

```
<div id="lienzo">
    <video id="video" class="oculto" preload="none" autoplay>
        <source src="video.webM" type="video/webM">
    </video>  
    <button id="snap" class="oculto">Tomar Foto</button>
    <canvas id="poo"></canvas>
</div>
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: I tried that too, but It didnt work

Comment: No help??, Please if the question is not clear enoght I can write down more clues, just give me an advice